# AWS RDS MySQL DB looses new columns after restart

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I'm working on an application for a client that has an RDS database on AWS with MySQL Community as the engine.

I added some columns in some tables for new features but I have a problem, every time the DB restarts, the new columns disappear, which makes the application crash.

I have added the columns via the database functionality built into Intellij, or via SQL scripts of which here is an example:

```
alter table visit
    add isVisited tinyint default 0 not null;
```

And here is the DLL of the table visit after modification :

```
-- auto-generated definition by intellij
create table visit
(
    id        int auto_increment primary key,
    date      datetime          not null,
    viewed    tinyint           not null,
    visitorId int               null,
    visitedId int               null,
    isVisited tinyint default 0 not null,
    constraint FK_18daeb99ad85ecca82a004588c5
        foreign key (visitorId) references users (id)
            on delete cascade,
    constraint FK_93cd362609c51b64018127a1048
        foreign key (visitedId) references users (id)
            on delete cascade
);
```

Any idea what could cause this ? I didn't created and configured the database (another dev dit it) but the configuration seems normal.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I see that the column name in ALTER and in DDL differs which is strange... a typo? Also - have you committed your structure altering?

Comment: Sorry I added the wrong SQL scripts, I edited my question. And no I haven't commited my modification, I thought that it wasn't necessary because ALTER is a DLL command that auto-commit by default ?